# htop with web interface

Tags: web, monitoring, htop

Is there any *simple and lightweight* monitoring tool like well-known **htop**, but with web interface? For Debian / Repberry Pi. All solutions I've seen was complicated and resource-intensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks everything works well!

In debian wheezy:

```
[sudo] service shellinaboxd stop
```

Becomes (without the letter 'd')

```
[sudo] service shellinabox stop
```

The same applies to update-rc.d line

```
[sudo] update-rc.d -f shellinabox remove
```

Answer (score 22):

I've found an interesting solution to run htop (and any other interactive console application) in browser — [shellinabox](https://code.google.com/p/shellinabox/wiki/shellinaboxd_man)

Install shellinabox

```
[sudo] apt-get install shellinabox
```

Stop  shellinabox daemon

```
[sudo] service shellinaboxd stop
```

Disable shellinaboxd autostart (in default configuration shellinaboxd serves http-ssh session on 4200 port)

```
[sudo] update-rc.d -f shellinaboxd remove
```

Now start shellinaboxd with own parameters

```
[sudo] shellinaboxd -t -b -p 8888 --no-beep \
       -s '/htop_app/:nobody:nogroup:/:htop -d 10'
```

Options:
**-t** — disable ssl (if necessary, not recommended for public servers)
**-b** — run in background
**-p** — web server port number
**--no-beep** — disable annoying beeps
**-s** *'…commands…'* —  session configurstion, where
**/htop_app/** — URL
**nobody:nogroup** — user and group for session (nobody:no group chosen for security reasons)
**htop -d 10** — command (actually session shell): run **htop** with **-d 10** argument (means update every second)

Now go to browser and navigate to

```
http://you_server_address:8888/htop_app/
```

Should look something like this ([screenshot](https://dzwonsemrish7.cloudfront.net/items/3P172J2O3i1f340m3u17/Screen%20Shot%202013-12-09%20at%2010.13.52.png?v=1ddfe3e0))

Comment: how do i stop it?

Answer (score 6):

`glances` is great! Use that!

https://nicolargo.github.io/glances/

https://iotrant.com/2019/09/03/keep-tabs-on-your-raspberry-pi-with-glances/

Very light dependencies -- basically just Python, `psustil`, `bottle` if you want to see it as a webservice...